# Update aspnetcore 3 preview 6 to preview 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying asp net core 3 preview 6 in a project, but now I want to migrate it to preview 7. I can't find the option in VS 2019 to do it. I have preview 7 installed, but it doesn't appear in the project properties either. How can I make the change?
Thank you very much for your help.

https://i.imgur.com/a/LnXFqSP

Comment: Please see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-7/

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in Visual Studio for this. Visual Studio just uses whatever is the default SDK version installed. The default is either the most latest version installed or whatever version is dictated by `global.json`.

In other words, in a command line run `dotnet --version`. Whatever is displayed there is what Visual Studio will use as well. If it's not what you want, add a `global.json` file to specify the exact version you want. If it's not the latest version installed, and you *want* it to be the latest version installed, then you most likely *already* have a `global.json` restricting it. Either change the version in the `global.json` or remove the `global.json` file entirely.

Also, .NET Core 3.0 Preview also requires Visual Studio Preview. In general, if you want to use the preview SDK, you need to use the preview Visual Studio as well.